# My SE profile shows "no activity found" when the 'all' tab is selected

Tags: bug, network-profile

https://stackexchange.com/users/1137539/cnst?tab=activity -- the *all* subtab by default, empty, shows *no activity found*, why?

https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/1137539?page=1&filter=all -- likewise, empty, shows *no activity found*, after a somewhat long delay, why?

https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/1137539?page=1&filter=posts -- not empty, as expected