# Activity page is blank

Tags: bug, recent-activity, network-profile

I usually catch up with whatever I last did on the Stack Exchange sites, by visiting [my activity page](https://stackexchange.com/users/3435/shreevatsar?tab=activity). However, over the last week or two, that page is often blank, even though the tabs other than "all" ("accepts", "posts", "comments", etc.) are not.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Blank activity page]

The corresponding activity pages on individual Stack Exchange sites (Stack Overflow, Math.SE, etc.) are fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I see. That question has no answer though.

Comment: Right, because it's a bug that wasn't yet fixed. Some bugs live for years, nothing we can do except report and be patient.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Was just commenting on the "This question may already have an answer here" banner. :) (It doesn't.) Anyway, that question is dated March 6, and so is [the other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224414/my-se-profile-shows-no-activity-found-when-the-all-tab-is-selected?lq=1) that has been closed as a duplicate of it, so I guess it's a very recent bug.

Comment: The keyword there is **may** but now it says just "This question is an exact duplicate of", no answers are mentioned. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: To me it shows "This question already has an answer here" and the info says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." :-)

Comment: Oh, you mean the close message itself. Yes it's bit buggy but I mean the top message, above the question body.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes to me, the top message above the question body says "This question already has an answer here". :-) (I've always thought it a bad idea to show question askers something no one else can see, but oh well...)

Comment: Weird, can you please take a screenshot? We might have stumbled over a bug here! (I just checked one [of my own questions closed as duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210958/network-profile-reputation-graph-does-not-obey-the-sanity-rules), target got no answers either but I see "This question is an exact duplicate of" on top. So maybe only if the close is less than 5 days old)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I guess it's a bug with the StackExchange app for Android, because in the browser I do see "This question is an exact duplicate of:" instead. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Oh, but it's still a bug, though minor. Feel free to comment on the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196581/questions-closed-as-duplicates-should-include-a-link-to-the-original-question) letting the dev know about the issue. :)